# Mysqli_real_escape_string with Single Quotes - Is it Safe?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, mysql-real-escape-string

So I know that using prepared statements with placeholders is pretty much the only way to protect yourself from SQL injection due to poor formatting of your queries.  However, I also see many people suggesting that, although mysqli_real_escape_string is NOT safe, using it with single quotes around the variable *is*.  For example (note the single quotes in the query):

```
$value1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($value1);
$value2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($value2);
$value3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($value3);

mysqli_query("INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, column3)
  VALUES ('" . $value1 . "', '" . $value2 . "', '" . $value3 . "')";
```

So: **when *only dealing with integers and strings*, would the above example be just as safe as if you were to use mysqli prepared statements and placeholders?**

Comment: No, regardless of which data types you're dealing with, _not_ using prepared statements will _never_ be as safe as using them.

Comment: @Don'tPanic - I would like to agree with your logic.  Any proof you could point me to?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263371/how-can-prepared-statements-protect-from-sql-injection-attacks

Comment: Basically, parameters bound to a prepared statement will inherently be interpreted as data. There isn't really a way to force them to be interpreted as commands instead.

Comment: And indeed that explains why prepared statements are safe.  But my question is whether or not this specific use of `mysql_real_escape_string` is also safe because it properly formats any possible string or integer.

Comment: Sorry, I must have misunderstood. I thought you were specifically asking if using `mysqli_real_escape_string` in that way would be as safe as using a prepared statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It is not `mysqli_real_escape_string` that is not safe**, but the way PHP users tend to use it.

As long as you are setting a character set with `set_charset()` **and** always wrapping your escaped values in single quotes, despite the type, then *technically* the statement above would be safe.

However, as you can see, there are too much rules to follow - a condition that is too complex for an average PHP user. Therefore, this kind of manual formatting *is* an endless source of injections, simply because any rule (escaping, quoting, setting a charset) could be just forgotten to apply.

Besides, manual escaping just makes your code bloated. Why not to let a program to process your data properly for you?

This is why you have to have a mechanism to apply all the rules automatically. So prepared statements is such a mechanism.

What's wrong with a simple function like this, any reason you want to prefer your code to it:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (?,?,?)";
some_query($sql, [$value1,$value2,$value3]);
```